# webView with https loadUrl shows blank page

Tags: android, ssl, webview

I used webview to visit https link. the page always show blank. i found the way to dill with it

```
public class WebViewClient extends Object
{
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) 
{
     handler.proceed();
}
}
```

That's work fine.

But i used API Android 2.1, the above method is belongs to Android 2.2. Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 17):

Hi I solved and blogged about this issue here:

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/

Regards,
Damian