# I cant access local web app deployed in tomcat using WebView Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to open a web app locally deployed in tomcat using `WebView`?

I tried using

```
webView.loadUrl("https://me.com/myproj/mobile/online/overview.do");
```

but I am getting a blank page instead. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to access a `https` address.

It seems that if you're developing for 2.2+ there's a simple solution:

```
engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed() ;
    }
}
```

But if you're developing for older versions, then you have problems because that function entered the API from Froyo.

References:

- [webView with https loadUrl shows blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697946/webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blank-page)
- http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/