# Open Url in webView in android

Tags: java, android, webview

How to open this [link](http://egov.uscis.gov/cris/Dashboard.do) in webView. This is running on browser but it does not run in webView android. Please give solution.

Comment: WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {


}
}

Comment: just check like as above

Comment: when i used other url that all run in webview

Comment: sounds like your data connection has low bandwidth. Just wait for a while for it to load.

Comment: send that url for me.. i will check it

Answer (score 43):

Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

And your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: i have done this other urls are running in webview but my url is not running. please check my url to open in webview.

Comment: yes you are correct. This link works. http://www.uscis.gov/portal/site/uscis but not specific page. It works when you access the URL via the phone browser. I will investigate some more.

Comment: OK, I think I know what it might be but don't have a solution.  The page that you call gets redirected to https://.  If you try looking at the page http://egov.uscis.gov/cris/Dashboard.do through a proxy like hidemyass.com you will see you get the same problem.

Comment: I just found this, may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121830/i-cant-access-local-web-app-deployed-in-tomcat-using-webview-android

Comment: Always happy to help.  Can someone up vote this so users can see there is a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check this out,
it has worked for me...but i dont know whether it got any side effects or not but works fine with me

```
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
       WebView theWebPage = new WebView(this);
       theWebPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       theWebPage.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON); 
       setContentView(theWebPage);
       theWebPage.loadUrl("http://www.hkmytravel.com");
```

Source can be found in [http://www.androidpanna.com/functionality/webview-open-url-webpage-within-the-android-app-when-launch-android-development]

Comment: @user8938 I have just enabled Java Script for the purpose of few other website that needs java script. Otherwise we may not need those two lines of code

Comment: Kindly tell me, why webview not opening simple url like, google.com, why we must add https or http as prefix of the url?

Answer (score 0):

Test the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me

```
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

XML

```
  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

add in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```