# Android open an EditText link using a button in Webview

Tags: java, android

I found this code in another post and I was wondering how I could make this url open in webView rather than the default Android browser.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LinkActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtLink;
Button btnOpenLink;
String defaultLink;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_link);

    defaultLink = "http://www.google.com";

    txtLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLink);
    btnOpenLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOpenLink);
    btnOpenLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String page = txtLink.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(page)){
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(defaultLink+"/"+page);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(LinkActivity.this, "Please enter page on editText!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

I would like this url to open in the app itself and not open the browser to go to the link. Any help would definitely be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Url in webView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269059/open-url-in-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `activity_link`, add a WebView object like below,

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and your LinkActivity should be look like below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LinkActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtLink;
Button btnOpenLink;
String defaultLink;
WebView mWebView;
String mUrl = "";
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_link);

    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    defaultLink = "http://www.google.com";

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    txtLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLink);
    btnOpenLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOpenLink);
    btnOpenLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String page = txtLink.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(page)){
                mUrl = defaultLink+"/"+page;
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(LinkActivity.this, "Please enter page on editText!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

// This method will reloads the last opened page in the web view..!
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    String url = mPrefs.getString("url", "");

    if (!url.equalsignorecase(""))
    {
        mUrl = url;
        txtLink.setText(url);
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}

// And this will save the last loaded link in the Shared Preferences(Local Storage)
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mPrefs.edit().putString("url", mUrl).commit();
}
}
```

and for more info about the webview, should refer the below url:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

To learn more about shared preferences, you can go on the below url:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thank you. How can I make it save the text entered in the textbox?

Comment: I did not understand..! where are you placing the textbox..?

Comment: Or are you want to use the textbox as a address bar?

Comment: Yes but I would like it to save the text and the next time the app is opened have the text from last time stored in the textbox.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check the `onResume` and `onPause` methods of the activity and i also edit the click listener of the button..

Comment: I want to save the text that the user enters where the page variable is. I want to save it and when the app is relaunched have the text that they entered the first time appear in the textbox. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you give an example? i don't understand what you want